# Form helper, nested resources without setting the parent resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-6, nested-resources

If we've models as:

```rb
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :chapters
end

class Chapter < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book
end
```

with routes:

```rb
resources :books do
  resources :chapters
end
```

and we want to create a form as:

```rb
<%= form_with(url: new_book_chapter_url(chapter) do |f| %>
```

How could we create this kind of form (`/books/:id/chapters/new`) without setting the `book` id ?

The example above will throw:

```rb
No route matches {:action     => "new",
                  :book_id    => nil,
                  :controller => "chapter"},
missing required keys: [:book_id]
```

In my case the user set the wished `book` within the form, and I'd like it to be `blank` when the form appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems here and I don't think you have actually understood the basics of RESTful routing in Rails or what nested routes should be used for.

If you want to create a chapter without specifying the book in the form action then you shouldn't be using a nested route. Just declare a non-nested route.

```
resources :chapters, only: [:create]
```

```
<%= form_with(model: chapter) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :book_id, "Select a book" %>
    <%= f.collection_select :book_id, Book.all, :id, :name %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When creating a resource you POST to the collection path (`/chapters`) not (`/chapters/new`). The `new` and `edit` actions in Rails are only used to display forms. This applies to both nested and non-nested routes.

You also should use the `model` option and just let Rails infer the route from the passed record. `url` should only be used when you must break the conventions or are using a form without a model.

See:

- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions
- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: Thanks for the reminders, indeed, RESTful routes aren't clear to me. Because I was thinking 'a chapter belongs to a book', I thought it'd be better to nest theses resources... Re-reading RoR guides is definitely needed !